# Can i pass a Bool as an environment object to subViews in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a bool

```
@State var isDragging: Bool
```

How can I pass this as an environment object to subViews?

Comment: You could encapsulate this property inside an object and use this as environment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create an ObservableObject:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isDragging: Bool = false
}
```

And then use:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var mymodel: Model

    var body : some View {
        if mymodel.isDragging { ... }
    }
}
```

And also, you should watch to WWDC 2019 session "Data Flow in Swift". Although some of the type names have been changed since, the concepts remain the same.

Comment: i thought about this, but i thought it was overkill for a single variable. Thanks

Comment: Note that this is necessary, because you specifically asked to used the Environment. However, if you only want to pass down and up the value to/from a subview, you can use a `@State` boolean and read it in the subview as a `@Binding`. Let me know if that is the case, and I'll update the answer.

Comment: i was thinking bout using the env, because i need this variable on many subviews.. is my only choice to pass the var down through parameters or to wrap it in this observable obj?

Comment: Yes, however, since beta 5 it is not that bad: you no longer need to define the Subject, nor use `willSet` anymore. ;-)